# text slider wordpress site .have any plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

how to show text with image slider in WordPress site . 
have any plugin to solve this problem ?   please help
slideshow plugin  I have a wordpress site I'm designing for a friends school. If you look at the home page: http://freelanceaccounting.co.za There is a slider there. Now i want to insert some text next to it But it doesn't work it either puts it above or below it. is there a plugin I'm ...

Answer (score 1):

Download this and use this Plugin this is free plugin and you can use all the thing in this plugin Video Images text and many more with all the things and you can animate your text images all options in this plugin.

[Download](https://www.downloadfreethemes.co/slider-revolution-v5-4-8-1-responsive-wordpress-plugin/)